# ASP.NET Menu Control - Keeping parent item selected

Tags: asp.net, css, menu

I have two ASP.NET Menu controls on a page.

One in my header (tabs) for top level pages, e.g. `~/Default.aspx`

And one in my sidebar for sub pages, e.g. `~/Products/SomeProduct.aspx`

I'm using the `selected` CSS class to ensure that the selected tab is a different colour.

Works fine for top level pages, but if I view a sub page, the tab isn't assigned a CSS class of `selected`.

How can I ensure that the top level menu item has a CSS class of `selected` when viewing a sub page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with help of related question:

[Set item.selected in ASP.NET Menu Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770042/set-item-selected-in-asp-net-menu-control)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuControl.MenuItemDataBound += new MenuEventHandler(MenuControl_MenuItemDataBound);
}

void MenuControl_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
    {
        if (SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Url == e.Item.NavigateUrl)
        {
            e.Item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My menu isn't databound so MenuItemDataBound is never fired.  Below is my solution to highlight the parent menu item when there are child items and when there are not:

Add a StaticSelectedStyle-xxx to the Menu, like `StaticSelectedStyle-BackColor="#757588"`

Call this method on Page_Load:

```
protected void SetSelectedMenuItem()
        {
            string pageViewed = this.Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;

            foreach (MenuItem item in Menu.Items)
            {
                if (item.ChildItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (pageViewed == item.Value)
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (MenuItem childItem in item.ChildItems)
                        {
                            if (pageViewed == childItem.Value)
                            {
                                if (childItem.Parent != null)
                                {
                                    childItem.Parent.Selected = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (pageViewed == item.Value)
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```