# Can't select a disabled or unselectable menu item

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am deploying a solution that I've been working on without issue in debug with the Visual Studio built in `IIS`.  I have two similar projects deployed on the same server with similar menu structures which work fine `ASP4.0 MSServer2012R2 SQL2018`.  For some reason, with this new project, whether I run in `localhost` or access the new site by url, I am able to hit the main page and login (indicating my DB connection and permissions are all ok), but when I click on any nested link in my menu bar, I get the error:

> Can't select a disabled or unselectable menu item. Error

I have found a little bit on this error, but everything points towards issues where "Selected" and "Enabled" were expressly set.  This is not the case here.  I do have role based authentication enabled, but that works IF it is a top level menu item.  As soon as I nest a menu, I get this issue.

This below will cause the issue

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/">
  <!--  <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/Default.aspx">
    </siteMapNode>   -->
    <siteMapNode title="Get Started" roles="Recruiter,Student,SuperUser">
      <siteMapNode title="About us" url="~/AboutUs.aspx"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode title="Help" url="~/Help.aspx" roles="Recruiter"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode title="Resources" url="~/Resources.aspx"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Manage Users" url="~/ManageUsers.aspx" roles="Administrator,SuperUser">
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

This Below will work:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/">
  <!--  <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/Default.aspx">
    </siteMapNode>   -->

  <siteMapNode title="About us" url="~/AboutUs.aspx"     roles="Administrator,User,SuperUser"></siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode title="Help" url="~/Help.aspx" roles="Administrator,SuperUser,User"></siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode title="Resources" url="~/Resources.aspx"></siteMapNode>

  <siteMapNode title="Manage Users" url="~/ManageUsers.aspx" roles="Administrator,SuperUser">
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

The Site map is bound:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-header">
                <asp:Menu ID="MasterPageMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemDataBound="MasterPageMenu_MenuItemDataBound">
                    <DynamicHoverStyle ForeColor="White"  />
                    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="main_menu" />
                        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level_menu" />
                    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="White" />
               </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

Here is the code behind for that:

```
protected void MasterPageMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
    {
        if (e.Item.Text == SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title)
        {
            if (e.Item.Parent != null)
            {
                e.Item.Parent.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent a couple of days on this now and know it will be something simple. . .but Im banging my head against the wall. . .any thoughts?

--Adding 3/10/20  Here is the complete IIS error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Can't select a disabled or unselectable menu item.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.SetSelectedItem(MenuItem node) +3099842
   myNewSite.SiteMaster.MasterPageMenu_MenuItemDataBound(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Gary\Documents\Gary\Trusted\uShine\Site.Master.cs:94
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.OnMenuItemDataBound(MenuEventArgs e) +139
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindRecursive(MenuItem node, IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable) +2950
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindRecursive(MenuItem node, IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable) +3030
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindItem(MenuItem item) +428
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.PerformDataBinding() +142
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +141
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +134
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.EnsureDataBound() +28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +37
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +227
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +227
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +227
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4005
```

Comment: Did you see any error message in F12 developer tool? Besides, did you see something wrong in event viewer?  I use your code on my side but I can't reproduce this issue even when I host it in IIS.

Comment: Thank you for trying. . .that helps me at least validate that the approach is sound.  Nothing shows up in dev tools, or I should say the errors I get from IIS seem to be the most instructive.  I've been dropping in debug statements trying to narrow down the issue. . .now its time to start deconstructing!

Comment: It so strange because I can't reproduce this issue on my side. Have you defined to use xmlsitemap provider instead of mysqlsitemapprovider?  It sounds like there was something wrong with data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me.  I encountered this post which in and of itself did not directly help me:

*[ASP.net Menu CSS parent node selected style without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502549/asp-net-menu-css-parent-node-selected-style-without-url)*

But I noticed that there were some indications that the item had to first be set selectable.  I had seen this in other posts, but ignored it because when I searched I found I didn't explicitly set ANYTHING as un-selectable.

Nevertheless, when I add this line, everything works, all pages are reachable and all errors go away.  Added lines marked as new below. . .

```
if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
{
  if (e.Item.Text == SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title)
  {
     if (e.Item.Parent != null)
     {
        e.Item.Parent.Selectable = true; //New GCS20200310
        e.Item.Parent.Selected = true;
     }
     else
     {
         e.Item.Selectable = true;  //New GCS20200310
         e.Item.Selected = true;
     }
   }
}
```

What is interesting to me. . .and I still don't understand. . . is still WHY are these pages unselectable if I am not explicitly setting them as such. . .and again, only if they are nested sitenodes.  Absent further evidence, it would seem that the act of nesting a sitenode makes it unselectable by default.