# Set asp:MenuItem as active

Tags: c#, menuitem

I have this asp:menu with a few items and want to be able to set an item as active when I've clicked it.

Here it goes

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/pages/page_a.aspx" Text="PageA" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/pages/page_b.aspx" Text="PageB" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/pages/page_c.aspx" Text="PageC" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

This renders a menu looking something like this

PageA PageB PageC

When clicking something like PageB I'd like to be able to style it somehow, like adding a css or whatever returning this

PageA **PageB** PageC

Any advices where I can find some info or samples?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770042/set-item-selected-in-asp-net-menu-control and http://forums.asp.net/t/1213831.aspx/1?Modify+Menu+adapter+to+show+selected+lt+ul+gt+element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a CSS class or styles to a menu item using the 'selectedstyle' properties of the asp:Menu control, using syntax like this:

```
      <staticselectedstyle backcolor=LightBlue
      borderstyle="Solid"
      bordercolor="Black"
      borderwidth="1"/>
```

A more full example is described in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

EDIT in response to comment:

There is also the 'dynamicselectedstyle' property for dynamic menus which used the same syntax:

```
      <dynamicselectedstyle backcolor=LightBlue
      borderstyle="Solid"
      bordercolor="Black"
      borderwidth="1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but my menu loads dynamically and staticselection isn't an option

Comment: One way to troubleshoot this would be to inspect the HTML which is produced when an item is selected and see what CSS classes .NET has applied to the menu item, that way you could just override those styles to achieved your objective.

Comment: Yes, did that but it seems as if im better of using another menu rendering technique. Thanks for your help.