# How to bind data to Treeview in asp.net with dynamic binding

Tags: asp.net

How to bind this data to treeview along with URL.

[image]

and Treeview would display like this

> [image]

But i dont know how to form a tree structure from this table. Please
 explain clearly how to bind this data to treeview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure it in a format you can loop through while building the TreeView. So, order the data by Dept, then Task, then Access. As you loop, watch for changes, so:

```
foreach (var dept in rows)
{
    if (prevDept == dept)
    {
        // Loop through tasks, etc.
    ...
```

Really, the best method would be to break this giant table into tiny tables and setup relationships. But, since I don't think you have much of an option at this point, this is your best shot.

Comment: How to structure and break this table?

Answer (score 0):

writing reply because cant' make comment due to low repo..
give it a look

[How to Create Dynamic Menu from Database using Menu control in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340709/how-to-create-dynamic-menu-from-database-using-menu-control-in-asp-net)

from this you will have an idea about db table structure and how you can bind table data to menu or tree view control.