# Get selected menu item from master page on content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code bebind as on page load event:

```
Menu menu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenuAdmin");
if (menu != null)
{
    MenuItemtext = menu.SelectedItem.Text;
    Response.Write("Selected Item is: " + MenuItemtext);
}
```

But gives error as:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenuAdmin" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal"
CssClass="navbar"
StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav"
StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu">
<Items>
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Candidate">
       <asp:MenuItem Text="GetList" NavigateUrl="~/LookupHandler.aspx" />
       <asp:MenuItem Text="AddNew" NavigateUrl="~/LookupHandler.aspx" />
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Update" NavigateUrl="~/LookupHandler.aspx" />
       </asp:MenuItem>
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Master">
       <asp:MenuItem Text="GetList" NavigateUrl="~/LookupHandler.aspx" />
       <asp:MenuItem Text="AddNew" NavigateUrl="~/LookupHandler.aspx" />
       </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So you get into the `if` but `menu.SelectedItem` is null?

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the variable named "MenuItemtext" is declared before the line.

```
MenuItemText = menu.SelectedItem.Text;
```

This can be the reason its showing you this error.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - This Error is shown when a variable or object is not declared and is used at runtime.

Try This code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Menu Menu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenuAdmin");
    Menu.MenuItemClick +=Menu_MenuItemClick;
}

void Menu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs Events)
{
    Menu Menu = (Menu)sender;
    MenuItem selectedItem = Menu.SelectedItem;
    Response.Write("Selected Item is: " + Menu.SelectedItem.Text + ".");
}
```

All that is required is you bind the Menu click event at PageLoad and process the clicked item in the MenuItemClick EventHandler.

Comment: I have declared that already but I don't know why it is not works..!

Comment: If it wasnt declared you would get a different **compiler error** (not a runtime exception).

Comment: can you post some more code from your aspx page (the html part) and also the part that is above this code in c# file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if the menu item  is not null

```
MenuItem selectedItem = menu.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem != null)
{
}
```

Comment: I get that as null but how to do that for getting selected value..!

Comment: I could be wrong but you're doing this on  page load so how would it know whats selected. You either have to select an item when the  menu menu is being bound  or hook into the menu click event and get the selected item that way

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770042/set-item-selected-in-asp-net-menu-control

Comment: So how I can bind event for that menu of master page on content page?

Comment: and here to hook into the menu click event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Menu control is on master page and I want to handle event on content page load event so how to do that?

Comment: Oh thank I write code for MenuEventHandler and it works, thanks!